# undefined local variable or method `resource_reset_password_token'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm trying to set up the **Devise** gem for my **Rails 5.1.4** development environment. I follow various examples and I still have the same problem.

Once I want to remind an forgotten password I get **undefined local variable or method `resource_reset_password_token'** error. The same error appears once mailer is not being configured. Here are some details:

**1. Error details**

N*ameError in Devise::Passwords#create
Showing /home/mk/thebest/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb where line #6 raised:
undefined local variable or method `resource_reset_password_token' for #<#:0xb1e74800>
Did you mean?  resolve_assets_with
Extracted source (around line #6):*

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action'), edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => resource_reset_password_token) %></p>
```

**2. config/environments/development.rb**

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.gmail.com",
    port: 587,
    domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
    authentication: "plain",
    enable_starttls_auto: true,
    user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
   }
```

**3. Environmental variables**
I've defined my env variables by adding them in that way:

sudo -H gedit /etc/environment

```
GMAIL_DOMAIN="gmail.com"
GMAIL_USERNAME="hereismyemail@gmail.com"
GMAIL_PASSWORD="hereismypassword"
```

without quotas doesn't work as well

**4. I've also allowed access in gmail**

using
http://www.google.com/accounts/DisplayUnlockCaptcha

**5. ENV**

Typing ENV command I can see my env variables are properly set up

Please support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<p><%= link_to t('.action'), edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @token) %></p>
```

From this thread -> https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/issues/4446

Comment: But it means Devise has a bug and I have to change the existing code? In such case I would find many such questions as I had... But I will try anyway

Comment: What devise version do you use?

Comment: You've generated views, so I've decided that you made some changes in it

Comment: I didn't make any changes within this prticular one. What I did was adding a bootstrab in other views. But: It Works! Thank you! I'm using Devise 4.3

Comment: When you told me all of this... I am not so happy with my solution, but I'm glad that it helped you

Comment: This is 2nd time I do this. What wired is for the first time it has been working well. Then I added dotenv gem and all troubles started. I had to checkout all changes and I even reinstall all my gemset. Not sure what happened. After I did totally the same as last time it was not working and I spend whole week on that bug looking for an answer before I asked for help. Good I can go further. Thank you Anton